# Matlab AWGN() function

Tags: matlab

How would do I add additive white guassian noise for an input SNR, without using the awgn() function on mat-lab?

Are there any resources available that can help me to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

The power of a normal distribuition (so the power of your white gaussian noise) is defined as variance ( \$\sigma_n^2\$) of the distribuition.

On MATLAB you can generate normally distributed random numbers using the function **randn** (see: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html ).
Before you generate your noise it's necessary to know what's the power of your signal, in that way you know what variance you noise has to have.